# Hungarian Algorithm - Bipartite Graph Approach

Tags: hungarian-algorithm

I have been having some difficulty making sense of the Hungarian Algorithm outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Bigraph_formulation).  It seems incomplete and/or erroneous to me.  The main issue is the line:

> If R_T ^ Z is nonempty, then reverse the orientation of a directed
>   path in...

How do we know which path to select as "a path"?  If we select the wrong path, how do we recover?  This seems to be a monotonically assigning algorithm, in that we can only ever create new assignments, but never remove or alter existing ones.

Suppose we have a simple example of S = {A, B}, T = {W, X} with weights AW: 2, AX: 2, BW: 6, BX: 4.  How do we select whether to add AW or AX to the mapping first, or how to we recover from making the wrong selection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the matrix interpretation, but it does look like there's a bit missing.

> How do we know which path to select as "a path"?

Just choose one; it doesn't matter which (as long as it's in *R<sub>T</sub>*). They should all be equivalent at this point.

> If we select the wrong path, how do we recover? This seems to be a monotonically assigning algorithm, in that we can only ever create new assignments, but never remove or alter existing ones.

This is the part that's missing, and as I'm not as familiar with the graph approach I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but it *is* allowed to alter existing assignments. The missing option is that you can swap an existing assignment to an unassigned edge of equal cost, allowing you to then make a new assignment. The harder part of this is finding the edge to swap to such that it doesn't conflict with any other assignments, and that by making this swap you are able to make a new assignment.

Comment: I think I've got the rough idea, which is that a path from R_S to R_T can go back and forth multiple times.  In that case, you would switch the directions of *all* the edges, which switches one more from S to T than the other way, thus causing one more assignment than unassignment, and so the logic holds.  But the argument is definitely more nuanced than explained there.